# How to have the changes stay?

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, direct2d

I have MainScreen.cpp

```
void MainScreen::Show(D2DResources* pD2DResources)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    ID2D1Bitmap* pBitmap=pD2DResources->GetpCurrentScreen();

    hr = pD2DResources->LoadBitmapFromFile(
        pD2DResources->GetpRT(),
        pD2DResources->GetpIWICIF(),
        L".\\Images\\MainScreen.jpg",
        0,
        0,
        &pBitmap
        );

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))pD2DResources->DrawScreen();
}
```

and at some point the MainScreen::Show() function is called like this

```
MainScreen->Show(&d2DResources);
```

However, it seems that as pD2DResources calls DrawScreen() in the MainScreen::Show() function, whatever was stored into &pBitmap didn't save. Actually, I get an unhandled exception and as it happens, pCurrentScreen, which should have received pBitmap's value, is 0x00000000.

What should I do?

Comment: Or is the problem in that small fragment of code at all?

Comment: I made some changes and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, LoadBitmapFromFile function failed 
So you should check LoadBitmapFromFile function's arguments 
However why did you assign pD2DResources->GetpCurrentScreen() to pBitmap?? 
Next line, pBitmap will be assigned with LoadBitmapFromFile function again. 
Additionally, If MainScreen's Show function called every frames, that is not efficient.
Because you don't have to load bitmap every frames. 
And d2d bitmap should be released.